# Why MySQL query doesn't match with what i though?

Tags: mysql

*sorry for my bad eng :(
Guyss...
Please help me,... i just learn MySQL, and i dont get why "permasalahan_khusus" doesnt match with "nama_psikolog" :(

please explain where did i go wrong

```
select 
    customer.nama_customer,
    psikolog.nama_psikolog,
    tipe_permasalahan.permasalahan_khusus
from
    customer
        cross join
    psikolog,
    tipe_permasalahan
where
    customer.id_permasalahankhusus = psikolog.id_permasalahankhusus = tipe_permasalahan.id_permasalahankhusus;
```

```
+------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| nama_customer    | nama_psikolog     | permasalahan_khusus |
+------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| Sarah            | Heryawan Bambang  | Kriminal            |
| Susi Chandrawati | Nur Hasanah       | Kriminal            |
| Jaka             | Marcella Sondakh  | Kriminal            |
| Cipto Tambunan   | Marcella Sondakh  | Kriminal            |
| Nina             | Marcella Sondakh  | Kriminal            |
| Anindyta         | Heryawan Bambang  | Kriminal            |
| Alyani           | Marcella Sondakh  | Kriminal            |
| Wisna Jaya       | Muhammad Firyanto | Kriminal            |
| Indra Cahyo      | Muhammad Firyanto | Kriminal            |
| Krisna           | Nur Hasanah       | Kriminal            |
+------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: What where you trying to achieve? instead of old school join try using this ```select 
    c.nama_customer,
    p.nama_psikolog,
    tp.permasalahan_khusus
from
    customer as c
    join psikolog as p on c.id_permasalahankhusus = p.id_permasalahankhusus
    join tipe_permasalahan as tp on p.id_permasalahankhusus = tp.id_permasalahankhusus```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JOIN` like this (coba pakai `JOIN` seperti ini):

```
SELECT 
    customer.nama_customer,
    psikolog.nama_psikolog,
    tipe_permasalahan.permasalahan_khusus
FROM
    customer 
JOIN psikolog ON customer.id_permasalahankhusus = psikolog.id_permasalahankhusus
JOIN tipe_permasalahan ON customer.id_permasalahankhusus=tipe_permasalahan.id_permasalahankhusus;
```

If this not working for you, update your question to include sample data from those three tables and also you expected output.